# C++ dynamic array size

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

So I'm currently reading about raytracing and wanted to test out a few things for myself to see if I understand the concepts. I looked up how to write a simple ppm file from http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html.

I am using visual studio 2015 and storing the rgb values for each pixel in a 2D array. The resolution of the image is 720p and each pixel had 3 integers for a red, green and blue so the array I made look like `int[720*1280][3]`.

I calculated that the total usage of memory should be 4 bytes(for the pointer to the 2D array) + 720*1280*(4+3*4) bytes(for the 720*1280 pointers each pointing to an array with 3 integers) which is approximately 14mb.

When I check the memory usage in visual studio it says that its using about 60mb of memory. What I would like to ask is where are the extra 36 mb coming from?

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "PPM.h"


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // WIDTH AND HEIGHT OF THE IMAGE
    const int width = 1280;
    const int height = 720;

    // 3 RGB VALUES FOR EACH PIXEL
    const int rgb = 3;

    // CREATE A BUFFER TO HOLD THE DATA
    int **data = allocateBuffer(width, height, rgb);

    // FILL IN THE BUFFER
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            data[y*width + x][0] = x %255;
            data[y*width + x][1] = y %255;
            data[y*width + x][2] = 0;
        }
    }

    // WRITE THE DATA TO A FILE
    saveImage("Test.ppm", width, height, data);

    // DELETE THE BUFFER
    deleteBuffer(data, width*height);

    // WAIT FOR INPUT TO EXIT
    std::cout << "Press ENTER key to exit\n";
    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**PPM.h**

```
#pragma once

// WRITES THE DATA TO THE FILE
extern void saveImage(char *filename, int width, int height, int **data);

// CREATES A BUFFER TO HOLD THE DATA
extern int** allocateBuffer(int width, int height, int rgbAmnt);

// RELEASES THE MEMORY
extern void deleteBuffer(int **buffer, int size);
```

**PPM.cpp**

```
#include "PPM.h"
#include <fstream>

// WRITES THE DATA TO THE FILE
void saveImage(char *filename, int width, int height, int **data)
{
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open(filename);
    file << "P3" << "\n" << width << " " << height << "\n255\n";
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            file << data[y*width + x][0] << " " << data[y*width + x][1] << " " << data[y*width + x][2] << "\n";
        }
    }
    file.close();
}

// CREATES A BUFFER TO HOLD THE DATA
int** allocateBuffer(int width, int height, int rgbAmnt)
{
    int size = width * height;
    int **data = new int*[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        data[i] = new int[rgbAmnt];
    }
    return data;
}

// RELEASE THE MEMORY
void deleteBuffer(int **buffer, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        delete[] buffer[i];
    }
    delete[] buffer;
}
```

Comment: I highly doubt your program declares just a single variable.  Second, your calculation does not include any extra overhead for things like "guard bytes" used for debugging memory corruption and any padding bytes that may occur.

Comment: Comment out the array declaration, then see what the memory usage is.

Comment: Sorry after thinking about my calculation I think the memory usage should have been much lower(should just be 1280*720*16) + 4 which is about 14mb. Cureently the program is very small, just 4 functions with a few ints and one c-string declared. I have a main function, 1 function to allocate the array and one function to delete it. The last function just writes the data to the file using and ofstream. I try and see if i can add the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a few words, when you ask for a memory block, you usually get more than what you asked for. Even though you don't know that.

That happens for several reasons. Here are some of them: 1st, for **performance**: several processors will run faster if the memory block is **aligned** along some boundaries, meaning the block addresses are multiple of some integer (usually a power of two); 2nd, for **granularity**, meaning the lower level software (the OS and your program's runtime library) prefer to manage blocks of a minimal size; and 3rd for the **management** of memory itself, meaning the lower level software will add headers (prefixes) and maybe trailers (or suffixes) to your data block. They will have information that will let these data blocks be allocated and liberated, and maybe some verification.

For instance, the size of the data block that was allocated, a pointer to the next block, and a checksum of the headers and trailers to make sure they weren't damaged by a careless or malignant program.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have read that there is some padding when you allocate memory, but I only expected it to be few bytes at most. Maybe its me calculation that is wrong and the actual amount of memory being used is actually closer to 60 bytes then.

Comment: Please consider your allocateBuffer routine. There you allocate lots of 3-int arrays. That has a lot of overhead, right ? There is padding and headers (and maybe trailers) for each one of them.

Maybe you could transform these in a larger chunk of memory, and access its individual components using pointer arithmetic. 

What do you think ?

Comment: After reading you comment I changed the buffer to be a 1D array and I a now the memory usage went down to around 11 mb. Thanks you very much. So is it reccomended to just use 1D arrays when possible since that will save memory?

Comment: I think it is a cost-benefit problem: if the resources that you use are scarce, it will pay back to try another strategy, even if is more complex or laborious. 

Otherwise, one can chose the easier way of doing things.  Thanks for considering this idea.